# Reporting coverage to sonarqube configured with cobertura from gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

My sonarqube server version 8.3.1 has the cobertura plugin enabled for showing cobertura coverage reports. Now I want to report jacoco XML-coverage data (generated with gradle jacoco plugin) and its not working. Are there any known issues between cobertura and jacoco? Or should both mechanisms work on one sonarqube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for someone running in this problem. The problem was that the plugin for importing jacoco xml files has been removed. If you use sonarqube its normally included. So if you can't see the coverage report check that the jacoco plugin has been installed.